# FullCalendar resource change when Google Calendar enabled

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I think I've found an issue regarding resource changes while having two event sources (my own API & Google Calendar's).

For the latest, I'm using the component in Resource timeline View, setting a callback property to change CSS for the column dates of received events.

```
eventDataTransform: function(event) {
                    $('td [data-date="' + event.start + '"]').css('background-color', '#e7e7e7');
                    $('th [data-date="' + event.start + '"]').css('background-color', '#e7e7e7');
                    //event.resourceId = 2089; DISABLED. Don't want a resource box for these events. 
                    return event;
                }
```

Since Resource Timeline view is designed to display events over resources, I made this change using **eventDataTransform** within Google Calendar source.

From that time on, changing event resource stopped working.

Any thoughts will be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry it's not clear what you mean. Are you saying that setting event.resourceId within the eventDataTransform function doesn't have any effect?  Can you please provide a [mre] of the issue and also state which version of fullCalendar you're using. There's nothing in the code you've shown which would appear to cause such a thing. Also, in your code you've commented out the line which sets the resource ID, so no-one would expect it to work in any circumstances.

Comment: Hey! I've updated the post for a better understanding. 

As I wanted to get GC's National holidays events and those events are not related to a specific resource, I was using that event source with the **eventDataTransform** callback to paint date cells using CSS.
(I commented that resource ID line because I don't want to display an event in the grid. Holidays means like Sundays to me).
That broke what I've been using so far, which was changing resources (not date events) from another event source in **resource timeline view** using **eventDrop** callback which is not being called anymore.

Comment: Why not just make them into a Background Event?

Comment: Yes, Background Event is much better. Anyway, is giving me the same results. Once you have both event sources activated, you can't drag an event where another is placed anymore.

Comment: That isn't the issue you originally described. But we don't have a [mre] of either of them, so it's difficult to know what else to suggest.  Please edit the question with a complete example, if you still need help

Comment: Found the problem while trying to make an reproducible example.
I was setting eventOverlap to FALSE. That won't allow me to drop events while other where placed (background events).

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah yes. That would make sense.  And it's another reason why we ask people to try and make such an example- reasonably often you solve it yourself due to that process forcing you to examine your code carefully. Glad you fixed it :-)

Comment: P.s. you should either add an answer below, or if you think it's of no interest to others, just delete the question. The solution doesn't belong as an edit within the question itself. (See also the [tour] if you're unsure how this site works).

Comment: Yeah, making it wasn't that easy because I have two event sources from APIs. Thank you very much again for your help & guidance.

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem while trying to make a reproducible example.

I was setting **eventOverlap** to FALSE. That won't allow me to drop events where others were placed (background events).

Thanks for your help @ADayson!